# Take ownership of folder

Tags: shared-folders

I want to add permissions to a shared folder (add an AD group) but someone told me to do that I have to take Ownership of the folder is this true?

Also, he said that, though he may have admin rights to the file share, as he is not the owner to some of the folders, to change permissions (add AD group), first he will need to take ownership, if he does this than any existing permissions to the folder will be lost. Is this true also?

I'm unable to test at the moment but would be grateful for some clarity on this.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to add permissions to a shared folder (add an AD group) but someone told me to do that I have to take Ownership of the folder is this true?

No. "Taking ownership" is **only** needed as an emergency override if nobody has the "Change permissions" access on that folder anymore. (This works because the owner has a special exception and can always change permissions.)

Whether permissions (access rights) can be changed is *itself* a permission that can be granted to various users; if you're using Windows 2008+ you can see this under "Advanced → Edit → Show advanced permissions". Usually most files and folders grant the "Read permissions" and "Change permissions" rights to the folder's owner and to Administrators, so taking ownership is unnecessary.

> Also, he said that, though he may have admin rights to the file share, as he is not the owner to some of the folders, to change permissions (add AD group), first he will need to take ownership, if he does this than any existing permissions to the folder will be lost. Is this true also?

No, taking ownership doesn't change current permissions. They're lost because someone deliberately resets them *after* taking ownership.

(For example, maybe the original owner changed all permissions to "deny" and the owner's account got deleted, so nobody is allowed to read or change permissions anymore. To recover from that situation, the first step is to take ownership, which grants you the "owner may change permissions" exception – but still doesn't allow you to read them or do anything else. Because you don't know what the current permissions are, your second step is unavoidably to "blindly" remove all old permissions and set new ones.

But if you're allowed to read current permissions, there's no need to completely reset them. And if you're allowed to change permissions, there's absolutely no need to "take ownership" either.)